# hovertree react (Переделать анимацию в react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, анимация

https://codepen.io/ceyhun1999/pen/xxJmomO

```
введите сюда код
```

Последняя моя надежда это написать сюда. Есть такая анимация нашел ее в сайте каком то hover.tree. Нужна сделать эту анимацию в react. Только ее код для меня очень сложный. Может кто ни будь видел или знает где найти ее в react

[image]

Comment: Мне ноут аж горячим воздухом дунул) А где вы хотите в реакте искать эту анимацию? Можете не искать её там нет

Comment: А в чем проблема просто прикрутить это к какому то компоненту реакта? Тем более, визуально, ему для работы нужен только тег canvas, а фукнцию и скопировать можно, что там указана в примере

Comment: Я пытаюсь реакт мне кучу ошибок выдает

Comment: Тогда берешь, выкладываешь код, как пытаешься и свои ошибки. А мы уже попробуем подсказать варианты возможного решения

Comment: я просто беру и вставляю это код в свой джс в реакте и он мне кучу синтактических ошибок выдает , я не знаю как вам это всё скинуть)

Comment: Берете и основные моменты вписываетет в ваш вопрос. Далее, можете попробовать создать пример, например в песочнице [https://codesandbox.io/](https://codesandbox.io/)